# About CRC in Data Link Layer

Tags: data-link-layer

Why the limit is 2^15 e.g 32768 can you elaborately explain?I am not getting this and how the generator divides if t >= 32768. I can’t make the calculations
[Tarenbum book screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlbUJ.jpg)

The approach or intution for the highest power of the generator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.